# can I use cluto and carrot2 tools to cluster tweets into groups?

Tags: tweets, carrot2, cluto

Can I use cluto and carrot2 tool to cluster tweets into groups?

And last question is carrot2 and cluto language independent NLP tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carrot2 to cluster any natural lanaguage texts, including tweets. Carrot2 is fairly language-independent and comes with support for the major languages out of the box.